# On sorting and filtering showing "An error occured, please try again later" in magento

Tags: ajax, magento

when I am clicking on any sort or filter option in category page it is showing an error occurred please try again please help.

[image]

```
<?php
class MageTracking_TicketSystem_Block_Ticketsystem_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->__('Ticket'));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();    
    }           

    public function getTickets(){

        return Mage::registry('ticketsystem_all');

    }

    public function getDepartments(){

        return Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->getAllCategories(false);

    }          

    public function getDepartment($id){

        return Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->getCategory($id);

    }   

    public function getPriority($priority){

        $priorites= Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->getPriorities();

        return $priorites[$priority];    
    }  

    public function getStatus($status){

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('ticketsystem/status')->getOptionArray();

        return $statuses[$status];

    }               
}
```

Comment: Are you using any custom extension for the layered navigation ?

Comment: i am using a marketplace extension

Comment: Try to search the error message in the extension files. If it exists there then edit the question with code. So that some one may help you.

Comment: i have not added any custom layered navigation

Comment: hello Muk i a not using any custom layered navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you are using [Tracking Ticketing System](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tracking-ticketing-system.html) extension in your site.

Go to line number 35 in following file `app\code\community\MageTracking\TicketSystem\Block\Ticketsystem\View.php`

```
class MageTracking_TicketSystem_Block_Ticketsystem_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->__('Ticket'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Following line is creating the problem

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('ticketsystem')->__('Ticket'));
```

You can check the error message in your browser console also.

Comment: @NirupamArya This is the default extension file. If you update your question with the actual code which you are having in your file on the site.Then I can try to help you. As the code in default file is correct.

Comment: please tell me which code you want from which location i will update

Comment: also this ticket tracking link is not showing in customer dashboard. so it is getting error please help i am new

Comment: Code from app\code\community\MageTracking\TicketSystem\Block\Ticketsystem\View.php file

Comment: @NirupamArya What do you mean to say?

Comment: <?php
/**
 * Magento Community Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Community Edition License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/community-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.